# Can not implement unit test on components with ionic 5/ angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, jasmine

I have created components and pages in my ionic 5 project.
The pages are working fine in unit tests.
But, the components are not being tested in the same way.

```js
describe('component', () => {
  let component: Component;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;
  let modalSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Modal', ['present', 'onDidDismiss', 'catch', 'dismiss']);
  modalSpy.onDidDismiss.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
  let modalCtrlSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ModalController', ['create', 'dismiss']);
  modalCtrlSpy.create.and.callFake(function () {
    return modalSpy;
  });
  let popoverSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Popover', ['present', 'onDidDismiss', 'dismiss']);
  popoverSpy.onDidDismiss.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
  let popoverCtrlSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('PopoverController', ['create', 'dismiss']);
  popoverCtrlSpy.create.and.callFake(function () {
    return popoverSpy;
  });
  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ Component ],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forChild(),
        ComponentsModule,
        PipesModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader }
        })
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ModalController, useValue: modalCtrlSpy },
        { provide: PopoverController, useValue: popoverCtrlSpy },
        AppGlobalState,
        IonContent,
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler,
        Http,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        Api,
        ConnectionBackend,
        SQLiteService,
        SQLite,
        InAppBrowser,
        RequestOptions
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.loading=false;
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }))

  afterEach(async () => {
    component.ngOnDestroy();
  })
```

This does not show the component being loaded.

```html
<ion-card *ngIf='loading'>
</ion-card>
<ion-card *ngIf='!loading'>
</ion-card>
```

```js
public loading: boolean = true

ngOnInit() {
  subscriber.subscribe(() => {
    this.loading = false
  })
}
```

another issue in the same code is when I added renderer2. It gives error can not read property style of undefined. for the function setStyle being used in code.

any help is appreciated.